# Html5 video not looping on Stable Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a background video that I need to autoplay and loop.

My html is:

```
<video class="mundoVideo" id="backVideo" autoplay autobuffer="autobuffer" muted="muted" width="1200" height="360" loop="loop">
   <source src="3D/1.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="3D/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="3D/1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

This way I can see it looping on Chrome and Firefox Nightly (even Internet Explorer 11), but Stable Firefox updated to latest version (32.0) don't.

I tried using just 'loop' as parameter, 'loop="loop"' or even with javascript like:

```
$("#backVideo").bind('ended', function(){ 
      this.play();
    });
```

But it seems that there's not ended event fired up, just the image stops at some point.

The web is: http://ticketcomunicacion.com/excelsior

Comment: What format is FF actually playing? Maybe it's format-related. Try including the .ogg version first, in front of webm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not be enough? If you have video, which you don't want changing:

```
$time = 39; // number of seconds of your video
setInterval(function(){
    $('#backVideo').load();
},$time*1000);
```

---

or try load() instead play() on your code. I don't have this version of Firefox, so I can't try it:

```
$("#backVideo").bind('ended', function(){ 
    this.load();
});
```

Comment: First script worked to force reload of the video. Thanks. I don't know why Firefox isn't working with the loop property